# how to add element to object in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects and it is structured as so:

```
let array1 = [{}]
array1.push({
   title: 'myTitle1',
   extendedProps: {
      field1: 'hello'
   }
})
```

now what I am trying is do an `axios.get` request and use the data returned to add a new element into `array1`. I am successfully retrieving the data from the axios request, however, when I try to push the data: `res.data[i]._doc.userIsReg`, like so:

```
array1.push({
  ...array1,
  extendedProps: {
        ...array1.extendedProps,
        userIsReg: true
  }  
})
```

as you can see, I am using the `spread` functionaluty to include the current data from `array1` into the array and then I try to append a new element `userIsReg` to the object `extendedProps`. Now, I assumed this would work, however, when I do this, it creates new object entries within the array and includes everything from inside the array currently (from spread functionality) and adds new entries with the `userIsReg` in there.

so to be more clear, I start with this:

```
[{
   title: 'myTitle1',
   extendedProps: {
      field1: 'hello'
   }
},
{
   title: 'myTitle2',
   extendedProps: {
      field1: 'hello2'
   }
}, 
]
```

and then once i do the `array1.push` with the spread functionality, i get this:

```
 [{
       title: 'myTitle1',
       extendedProps: {
          field1: 'hello'
       }
    },
    {
       title: 'myTitle2',
       extendedProps: {
          field1: 'hello2'
       }
    }, 
    {
       title: 'myTitle1',
       extendedProps: {
          field1: 'hello',
          userIsReg: true
       }
    },
    {
       title: 'myTitle2',
       extendedProps: {
          field1: 'hello2',
          userIsReg: true
       }
    }, 
    ]
```

so basically doubles everything up, instead of appending it to the current array. how would i fix this?

Comment: Do you want to add `userIsReg` field to the EXISTING array elements after receiving response, am I right?

Comment: @Azamat yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following once you have response

```
array1.map(element => ({...element, userIsReg: true}))
```

It will add userIsReg flag to each object of your array.

Now as you want it inside `extendedProps`, you can use following

```
array1.map(element => (
    {...element, 
    extendedProps: {
       ...element.extendedProps, 
       userIsReg: true 
    }}))
```

Answer (score 0):

as you defined your array in let type you can do it in this way:

```
array1 = [...array1.filter(item=> item.title === selected_item.title ),{
  ...selected_item,userIsReg: true 
}]
```

what I did is to just remove the previous element and add a new one with a new value
if you want to preserve order of array you can sort that

Answer (score 0):

Try this way **:**

```js
let array1 = [{
   title: 'myTitle1',
   extendedProps: {
      field1: 'hello'
   }
},
{
   title: 'myTitle2',
   extendedProps: {
      field1: 'hello2'
   }
}];

array1.forEach(obj => {
    obj.extendedProps['userIsReg'] = true // this value is coming from API
});

console.log(array1);
```